# How to create a custom image for raspberry pi 2?

Tags: raspbian, operating-systems

The more speciefic question is.
I would like to create an image with:

1. Some pre-installed programs
2. Some custom theme (nothing complicated, wallpaper, colors, etc)
3. Some animation while booting (just a simple image)

I was thinking to donwload the Raspbian lite, install some GUI and do the steps above. Then make a image with it.

Is this the correct approach? Does anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will work (it is commonly referred to as a golden image). You may want to forgo Raspbian Lite and go for the full Raspbian which already includes the GUI. If you are planning to use this image on multiple Pi's there are a few things to note. The SSH keys and base hostname will all be the same (the hostnames may have a digit added after raspberrypi) - this can make it difficult to identify the machine on your network, and in the case of SSH keys is a security issue.

If you want to take a too the next level, or plan to setup several Pi's with the same default setup check out config management software like puppet, chef or ansible.